# letsencrypt / certbot fails after upgrade

Tags: lets-encrypt, certbot

I just received an email from Let's Encrypt stating:

```
Beginning June 1, 2020, we will stop allowing new domains to validate using
the ACMEv1 protocol. You should upgrade to an ACMEv2 compatible client before
then, or certificate issuance will fail. For most people, simply upgrading to
the latest version of your existing client will suffice.
```

I did the following to upgrade on Debian 9:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- It proceded to upgrade many packages but said certbot was being held back
- I then did sudo apt-get upgrade certbot
- It upgraded certbot (as well as python3-acme, python3-certbot, and python3-certbot-apache). It also installed a new package (python3-requests-toolbelt).
- Everything seemed to install fine
- I then ran sudo certbot renew --dry-run

On the dry-run I got several errors as follows (some items have been REDACTED by me as I wasn't sure if it was sensitive info to post here):

```
Attempting to renew cert (mail.example.com) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mail.example.com.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. mail.example.com (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: Invalid response from http://mail.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/REDACTED_STRING_EXAMPLE [REDACTED HEXADECIMAL ADDRESS]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p". Skipping.
```

and

```
 The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: mail.example.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://mail.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/REDACTED CODE
   [REDACTED HEXADECIMAL ADDRESS]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC
   \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

What is causing this issue? I do not have a .well-known directory in my root web directory. Is this a new requirement that I need to add? If so, what can I do to fix my certbot so that I can correctly renew my certificates?

Comment: It seems like certbot isn't hosting the webserver properly. You might want to do a manual renew first and then check if the auto-renew works.

Comment: Which web server are you using ? Nginx ? Apache ? You may need to install a python plugin like python-certbot-nginx or python-certbot-apache

Comment: you need to provide more info, like web config for the domain, which command exactly are you running with certbot, and I hope mail.example.com is redacted and not the hostname in question? :)

Comment: @AlexisTacnet I am using Apache. I have python-certbot-apache installed (and is the latest version).

Comment: @Ron I gave the command I am running with certbot in my post. example.com is indeed not my actual domain name. Is it customary on SO to use example.com rather than your actual domain name.

Comment: @kojow7 can you confirm that `dig domain.com @1.1.1.1` and `curl ip.me` result to the same IP address?, also there is no need to redact `REDACTED CODE
   [REDACTED HEXADECIMAL ADDRESS]` as those are one time hashes and do not pose a security risk. Also make sure the apache user is able to create folders `.well-known/acme-challenge/` and files in there, and as @Alexis Tacnet mentions make sure all that is possible via port 80

Answer (score 0):

So, as I saw that you are using Apache, I think that it is wrongly configured to serve properly the ACME Challenge.

What `certbot` is doing is creating the `.well-known/acme-challenge/` folder and then adding it to your Apache configuration for the website (here `mail.example.com`). So my guess is:

- Check that you have a `mail.example.com` configuration in Apache (`/etc/apache2`). You can dump all your current active configurations with something like `apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS`.
- Check your `mail.example.com` configuration in Apache and especially the `:80` part where `certbot` is gonna try to insert code.

I think that you have an issue here as `certbot` is unable to make the `.well-known` folder available (over **HTTP, port 80**). Check your `<Directory>` tags in your configuration to try to understand where Apache is redirecting your traffic.

Comment: My mail.example.com is working fine with Apache. In fact I am using the site now with https via certbot. However, after upgrading to version 2, certbot renewal is failing. Nothing has changed in my Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the automatic verification fails, especially with custom configurations in place.
If not done already, check out the [certbot documentation for HTTP-01 Challenge](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/challenges.html?highlight=challenge). The important parts

> When using the Webroot plugin or the manual plugin, make sure the the
> webroot directory exists and that you specify it properly. If you set
> the webroot directory for example.com to /var/www/example.com then a
> file placed in
> /var/www/example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/testfile should appear
> on your web site at
> http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/testfile (A redirection
> to HTTPS is OK here and should not stop the challenge from working.)
> ...
>
> Make sure your web server serves files properly from the directory
> where the challenge file is placed (e. g. /.well-known/acme-challenge)
> to the expected location on the website without adding a header or
> footer.

[This tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-10/) describes how to allow acme http requests with apache server.

In short:

To make it simple you can map all HTTP requests for             .well-known/acme-challenge to a single directory,             /var/lib/letsencrypt.
Therefor you should create the directory beforehand.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/letsencrypt/.well-known
sudo chgrp www-data /var/lib/letsencrypt
sudo chmod g+s /var/lib/letsencrypt
```

Then to make sure the folder is accessible you can use the following config snippet

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ "/var/lib/letsencrypt/.well-known/acme-challenge/"
<Directory "/var/lib/letsencrypt/">
    AllowOverride None
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
    Require method GET POST OPTIONS
</Directory>
```